How to describe a position in English?
As I know, if there are two things distributed in front of me like below, I can say there two items going "left to right". If I want to specify a particular one, "the right one" or "the one on the right" can be used. Is this right? Or should I use some more natural expressions?

In the condition of the case below, things beyond me.

Are those expressions natural, or do I need some more natural expressions?
Further, if I want to learn more about this topic, how should I google it? When I search "Directions in English" with google, I can't get the knowledge I want.

The right one clearly has more than one meaning. So not that.

I am a native speaker and would understand the one in front of me, to mean the one that is nearest to me. The answer below has a good suggestion as to how you can communicate this clearly.

It's "position" not "postion".

If there are two items, you might call them the one on the left and the one on the right. If there are several items, it would often be useful to refer to the leftmost or the rightmost one.

The one in front/behind of me.

I'd use

Thing on my left, thing on my right;
Thing further away from me, thing closer to me.


Note that "in front of" can mean "closer to me", which in this situation is the opposite meaning to what you want.

@Peter - Exactly. If you are speaking to another person about two objects that both of you are facing, "the one in front" is the one nearer to you.

It can get confusing when specifying directions. It's important to think about how things look to your listener as well. For example, if I face you and say "walk left," I will see you move in a direction that looks like right to me. To solve this, people often say "your left," though they often forget to and have to add it after the listener does the wrong thing.
This can get further complicated. What if we look at a painting of The Last Supper and I say "The man on Jesus's right"? Do I mean "to the right of Jesus, as it appears to us the observers?" Or "the man who would be on our right if we were in Jesus's place?"
It could get even more confusing: what if I don't know the exact location and orientation of the person I'm talking to? What if I'm speaking to a crowd of people who are all around me? If I show several objects, their spatial relationships will look different to all the people.
Since all this is so confusing, the very best thing to do is to be as clear and explicit as possible. Are there any other ways of identifying these objects other than their spatial relationships? Can we say "the red one" or "the blue one"? If we must rely on spatial orientation, try to be as specific as possible. "The one immediately in front of me. The one farthest from me. The middle one on the left, as you face me."
In dramatic theater contexts, we say "stage left," "stage right," "upstage" and "downstage" to eliminate this confusion and make it clear that we mean "from the point of view of someone on the stage, not a spectator in the audience."
